# How to access MySQL after deleting all MySQL users?

Tags: mysql

I deleted all users by mistake and now I can't access MySQL.
I searched too much but I can't access MySQL 
I can't remove it && reinstall again
I delete all users from table user from database MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

#### How to restore the root user

Stop MySQL and edit `/etc/my.cnf` to contain `skip_grant_tables`:

```
[mysqld]
skip_grant_tables
```

Then restart MySQL with `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.

Start the MySQL CLI:

```
[root@test ~]# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>
```

Then enter the following query (replace NEW_PASSWORD_HERE):

```
INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user`(`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`, `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`, `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`) VALUES ('%', 'root', PASSWORD('NEW_PASSWORD_HERE'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0');
```

You now have a working root user.

#### Restore

Now that you have access to your database, please restore from a backup
(you *do* have backups, do you?)